# Magento event on stock change?

Tags: events, magento, inventory, stock

is there an event whenever the stock quantity of an product is changed?

**I tried:**

```
cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after
_after and _before.
```

But this event only get triggerd if product is saved, but not on sell or order cancel.

So is there a convinient event for this?

Thanks and cheers,
Matthias

Answer (score 2):

`cataloginventory_stock_item_save_commit_after` gets triggered on sale.

Comment: It looks like that only holds true if the sale triggered stock notifications, otherwise the stock model is optimized to update the stock quantity in a single query which triggers no event (Magento CE 1.7)

Comment: @fab could you show me how config for "the sale triggered stock notifications"?

Comment: @HoangLan it is not about configuration. The stock qty can change if items are sold (=> triggered by sale) or on other occasions like when you set it in the backend, then the event is not triggered